# SenseHat; Random Pattern using FrameBuffer: No Error?

Tags: led

[This Raspberry Pi Post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/buy-the-sense-hat-as-seen-in-space/) talking about the SenseHat gives the following example to fill up the LED matrix with random colours:

```
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/fb1
```

This works: but also generates the following error:

```
cat: write error: File too large
```

I can use 'dd' instead

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/fb1 count=1 bs=128
```

This works: and doesn't give an error: but I just got the figure of 128bytes from trial and error - what is the real size to use here ?

[Also: can somebody add 'SenseHat' to the list of tags ; it seems we should have this here?]

Comment: try use sudo before the cat command?

Comment: Thanks - makes no difference - the framebuffer is apparently 128bytes in size; and anything over that will result in the error (same with the dd if I use 'bs=129 count=1'.

Comment: Sorry it was just a guess. I don't know that much about the frame buffer ;(